# jQuery detect if div is outside of view port vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect when my div gets opened is the top of it outside of the view-port & if it is add a class to adjust the css.

So basically in this example on hover half of the div is missing so that should then add the class that would turn the div green. Because the code is meant to detect that the div is outside the viewport.

But I just cant get it to sync. I'm obviously doing something wrong here.

**UPDATE**

I have just noticed that it technically is working what is happening if both the top and bottom of the div goes outside of both the bottom and top of the view port then it triggers. I need it to only trigger when it goes out of the top.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L8gbvmd/)

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
  $(this).children(".infotip").addClass("active");
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
  $(this).children(".infotip").removeClass("active");
});

// Infotip on screen
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip.onscreen')", function() {
  var $target = $(this).children(".infotip");
  if ($target.length) {
    var $bounce = $target.offset().top + $target.height();

    if ($bounce > $(window).height()) {
        $target.addClass("test");
      } else {
        $target.addClass("top");
      }
    }

});
```

```css
.infotip {
  display: none;
  height:500px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:-250px;
}
.infotip.active {
  display: block;
}
/* goes red when past top of viewport (which it will not do in this example) */

.infotip.top {
  background-color: rgba(249, 14, 18, 1.00)
}
/* goes green if visible (which it should do when hovering) */

.infotip.test {
  background-color: rgba(35, 223, 51, 1.00)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-card align">
  hover me
  <div class="infotip onscreen">
    Iam infotip
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was the issue, `on-hover` it detect `div height` and if it `overflows` then changes the div to `green`.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", function() {
  var $target = $(".team-card").children(".infotip");
  if ($target.length) {
    var $bounce = $target.offset().top + $target.height();

    if ($bounce > $(window).height()) {
        $target.addClass("test");
      } else {
        $target.addClass("top");
      }
    }

});
```

Comment: I take it you never tested this as it really doesn't do anything. All you have done is change my selectors.....

Comment: @DCdaz I have made changes in your selector, as I need to check that when height of .infotip goes out it should turn green. So .infotip is what I need to target.

Comment: all you have done is change the selector it doesn't effect anything else.

Comment: no it's not. it doesn't matter I sorted it out as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out myself. Finally had a brain storm after realising what the height was down as mentioned on my update.

What I should have been doing is calculating the distance from the top and then detecting if that distance is less than one e.g. 0, -5, -250 etc. Then kick my statement in.

Just wasn't thinking about this one in the right manner for a bit.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2L8gbvmd/2/)

```js
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
  $(this).children(".infotip").addClass("active");
});
$(document).on("mouseleave", ":has('.infotip')", function() {
  $(this).children(".infotip").removeClass("active");
});

// Infotip on screen
$(document).on("mouseenter", ":has('.infotip.onscreen')", function() {
  var $target = $(this).children(".infotip");
  if ($target.length) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $target.offset().top,
    bounce = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

    if (bounce < 1 ) {
        $target.addClass("test");
      } else {
        $target.addClass("top");
      }
    }

});
```

```css
.infotip {
  display: none;
  height:500px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:-250px;
}
.infotip.active {
  display: block;
}
/* goes red when past top of viewport (which it will not do in this example) */

.infotip.top {
  background-color: rgba(249, 14, 18, 1.00)
}
/* goes green if visible (which it should do when hovering) */

.infotip.test {
  background-color: rgba(35, 223, 51, 1.00)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-card align">
  hover me
  <div class="infotip onscreen">
    Iam infotip
  </div>
</div>
```